# React Native Expo on LAN, allways run the same app

Tags: expo, react-native, wifi

If I want to connect via lan in different React Native projects, the same app always loads me, if I do it with Tunnel if the current app loads me,

I have seen that if I change WIFI, the LAN connection works and it loads the current app, but if I return the WIFI from my house, again the problem, it always loads the same app (old app)

Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: So you are working on different RN projects at the same time, say app A and app B, and when reloading let's say app B, it still loads the content of app A? And this behaviour changes when you switch using to Tunnel?

Comment: That's right, this only happens in my home Wifi, if I go to another Wifi I can see app A and B in LAN connection, but if I'm at home, app A always loads me over LAN, only if  I connect by Tunel I can load the app B

Comment: Hmm, I suspected the home wi-fi dns settings at a first glance. It maybe fetching a static ip instead of a dynamic one. And, it is a better idea to check ip and ports indicated in your Expo client app if you are using a managed workflow (using Projects tab). Lastly, please make sure you have the latest expo-cli and expo app versions.

Comment: a couple of months ago, it worked with my house wifi, but when I put in production mode and went back to developer mode, I could never connect again in LAN,I don't know if it was bugged or something like that,

Comment: To eliminate this possibility, you should upgrade your environmental tools (expo-cli and expo app). Another thing that comes to my mind is to reset .expo folder in your root, simply delete it and restart your project (please make a backup first)

Comment: I'll try that, and I'll tell you what happened right away

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like Expo client is unable to connect to your computer over LAN and so it is falling back to the cached version from the last successful loading attempt

Comment: Is there a way to delete that version in cache, to force it to look for a new one?, I try with `exp r -c`, but still not working